# Sitecore: How to list a set of items which composed a newsletter

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have the following requirement from the client:

I will have to list, in a Sub Layout that will be part of a web site page, a set of Items.

Those items will compose a newsletter.

Each Items ("Article") will have to be listed (Name of Article + Link to view the article)
What would be the logic here ? How can I retreive those article ?
Should that be created in a specific folder and than parse the folder in C# ?
Could we retrieve the Items path by parsign / looking into the newsletter items itself ?

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

### Using an Index

For optimization, you probably want to create an Index of the items you want to list.  You can do so without, but you will start having performance issues with large numbers of articles.

The following code block shows an example of one way to load items out of an index.  If you google, you can find a bunch of information on this, especially using the [Advanced Database Crawler.](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches against the Lucene index for all articles
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Item> LoadArticlesWithLucene()
    {
        ConcurrentBag<Item> articles = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();

        Index searchIndex = SearchManager.GetIndex("MyArticleIndexName");
        using (IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            //The wildcard search allows us to pull back all items from the index
            var query = new WildcardQuery(new Term(Constants.LuceneFields.Name, "*"));
            SearchHits hits = context.Search(query);

            //Go through the results 
            SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(0, hits.Length);

            Parallel.ForEach(results, result =>
            {
                //This is done in a foreach in case you want to add any processing or checking before adding to your collection
                Item searchItem = result.GetObject<Item>();
                articles.Add(searchItem);
            });


        }

        return articles.ToList();
    }
```

You still need to create the index, and if you are using the advanced database crawler module you just need to add some configuration to your Sitecore instance that looks like:

```
    <search>
        <configuration>
            <indexes>
                <index id="MyArticleIndexName" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="folder">__news</param>
                    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
                    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
                        <master type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler">
                            <Database>master</Database>
                            <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
                            <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
                            <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                                <article>{3DD181B0-0F39-4E7A-8C94-DFA129DE6C81}</article> <!-- Replace the GUID here with yours -->
                            </include>
                            <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
                                <!-- Multilist based fields need to be tokenized to support search of multiple values -->
                                <fieldType name="multilist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                                <fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                                <fieldType name="treelistex" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                                <fieldType name="checklist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                            </fieldTypes>
                        </master>
                    </locations>
                </index>
            </indexes>
        </configuration>
    </search>
```

### Pulling from Sitecore without an Index

If you are pulling from Sitecore without an index, you will want to find all the descendants that have a specific Template ID or Name (your Article Template).  There are multiple ways to do this, but you might use an extension like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns every item below the current item which has the specified template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="templateName">Template of items to return</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Item> GetAllDescendants(this Item item, string templateName)
    {
        return new List<Item>(Context.Database.SelectItems(item.Paths.LongID + "//*[@@templatename='" + templateName + "']"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will need to try this weekend. One question about your code: Does that mean the article list should be fixed ? If the editor is creating 5 Articles but only three are used inside the newsletter, how can I control which articles have been used or not ?

Comment: The above sample is for a very simple template-based filtering.  You can do more advanced filtering by field values or something of the like, or have separate templates for 'Newsletter' Articles and 'Non-Newsletter' Articles, both inheriting from Article template, so you can still filter by template without having to duplicate fields.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use a Treelist field, place some datasource/template restrictions and let the editor select which articles (and in which order) they want included in the newsletter?

http://firebreaksice.com/tame-your-sitecore-treelists/

Unless you really do want something that is totally dynamic and without user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

### Item Buckets

You may want to consider the Item Bucket shared source module, which allows you to store a very large number of items in one place in your content tree and to search by taxonomic categories.  This will support your current requirements, and support presenting this content in new ways as your requirements evolve, for example, to show articles on related topics in a sidebar.

From the [Github documentation:](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Item-Buckets)

> Sitecore Item Buckets addresses the management of large amounts of items within the content tree and being able to retrieve and work with them in a speedy and efficient manner. To decide if you should turn an item into a bucket, and in-turn, hiding all its descendants, is as simple as asking yourself if you care about the structure of the data that lives under the bucket. For example, if you had a Product Repository, Movie Repository or Tag Repository within the content tree, you would most likely want to just dump them all into a folder and when you want to work with a particular product, movie or tag, you would simply search for it and open it.

The Item Bucket has some impressive features, such as a very clean user interface, the ability to tag items, and the ability to run LINQ queries against these tags.  Here's an example from the Github documentation.

```
var movies  = new BucketQuery().WhereContentContains("Dark")
                           .WhereTemplateIs("{D3335D0B-D84D-46AF-C620-A67A6022AB3F}")
                           .WhereLanguageIs(Sitecore.Context.Language)
                           .WhereTaggedWith("Tag ID for Tim Burton")
                           .WhereTaggedWith("Tag ID for Johnny Depp")
                           .WhereTaggedWith("Tag ID for Helen Bohnam-Carter")
                           .Starting(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-12))
                           .Ending(DateTime.Now)
                           .SortBy("_name")
                           .Page(1, 200, out hitCount);
```

Item Buckets were introduced at Sitecore Symposium in 2012. Although this is a shared source module, is is supported by Sitecore and was featured in the Symposium keynote as an Enterprise-ready solution for dealing with large data sets in the Sitecore content tree.

#### Links:

- [PDF Manual](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Item-Buckets/blob/master/documentation/Item_Buckets_Developer_Guide-SC64-66-USLetter.pdf)
- [Sitecore Marketplace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Item_Buckets.aspx)
- [Github](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Item-Buckets)